# Java How to add JOptionPane Messages on Method

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm making a GUI in which user enter any movie name.If the database has that movie then it appear on ide console if not then show message.Now program give correct output on ide console when user enter any related movie which is in database.But the problem is when enter any wrong name of movie which is not in database then program doesn't do any thing.I want to give a `JOptionPane` message when nothing found from database just like this
[image]

And when data found.
[image]

But i don't know how to do this.
Code:

```
public class Find extends JFrame{

    private JLabel keyword;
    private JTextField tx;
    private JComboBox box;

    private  Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement pre;
    private ResultSet set;
    private ResultSetMetaData meta;

    String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo";
    String user="root";
    String pass="pass";



    public Find(){
        super("Frame");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);


        keyword= new JLabel("Keyword");
        keyword.setBounds(170, 100, 96, 37);
        getContentPane().add(keyword);


        box = new JComboBox();
        box.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Title"}));
        box.setBounds(42, 139, 63, 20);
        getContentPane().add(box);


        //textfield
                tx= new JTextField();
                tx.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {


                    try{

                        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(server,user,pass);

            String option = (String) box.getSelectedItem();
            String query = "select title,year from movies where "+option+"=?";
                             //statement
                pre     =  conn.prepareStatement(query);                    


                pre.setString(1, tx.getText());



                set=    pre.executeQuery();



                ResultSetMetaData meta = set.getMetaData();


                int totalcolumn=meta.getColumnCount();



                while(set.next()){

                      for(int i=1;i<=totalcolumn;i++){

                          System.out.printf("%-8s\t", set.getObject(i));


                      }

                      System.out.println();           

                  }

                    }
                    catch(Exception e1){

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
                    }



                    }
                });
                tx.setBounds(120, 136, 202, 27);
                getContentPane().add(tx);




        setSize(450,450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);   
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class FindMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Find ooper = new Find();

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, formatting your code better will attract more help

Comment: @BoDidely now i correct my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check if your query returns an empty ResultSet. The method isBeforeFirst() returns false if the cursor isn't positioned before the first row **or if the set contains no rows**

```
if (!set.isBeforeFirst()) {    
    //Here you can display your 'failure' JOptionPane 
} 
else {
    //Here you can put your code that handles your set, including your 'success' JOptionPane
}
```

For example I would propose this change:

```
...
    set = pre.executeQuery();
    if (!set.isBeforeFirst()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The record was not found.");
    }
    else{
        ResultSetMetaData meta = set.getMetaData();
        int totalcolumn=meta.getColumnCount();
        while(set.next()){
            for(int i=1;i<=totalcolumn;i++){
                System.out.printf("%-8s\t", set.getObject(i));
            }
            System.out.println();           
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception e1){
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you added the code in the proper section? What is the exception?

Comment: Yes, your current code executes a database query on every key release. There is currently no code to recognize when the person is "done typing".

Comment: so which method is used

Comment: It entirely depends on how you want to implement this.. One solution would be to use an ActionListener to trigger your code as this would only trigger if the user pressed enter while focused on the text field instead of on each keypress.

Answer (score 1):

set.getObject(columnIndex) returns null if the result of executing the SQL query is NULL. But before you get there, check to see if set has any elements.

Try the following:

```
 ResultSetMetaData meta = set.getMetaData();

 int totalcolumn = meta.getColumnCount();

 if (!set.next() ) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No data");
 } else {
       do {
          for(int i = 1; i <= totalcolumn; i++) {
               System.out.printf("%-8s\t", set.getObject(i));
          }

          System.out.println();
      } while(set.next());
 }
```

Comment: Check to see if you have any elements returned from the query, afterwards you can proceed with printing the results. If there are no results, just show your popup.